# I can't plot using pyplot in julia

Tags: julia

So I'm trying to plot [this function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhxod.png) using PyPlot in julia
here's what I did:

```
using PyPlot

theta0 = 160

theta = range(0,stop=180,length = 50)
m1 = 4
m2 = range(1,stop = 200,length = 50)
d = pi/180
function km(m,th)
    ((sqrt((m/m1)^2-sin(th*d)^2)+cos(th*d))/(1+(m)))^2
end
PyPlot.plot(m2,km(m2,theta0))
```

and I get [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0i5ei.png)

I can't find anything wrong, please help.

Comment: Write `@.` in front of line `((sqrt((m/m1)^2-sin(th*d)^2)+cos(th*d))/(1+(m)))^2` to make it broadcast over elements of arrays. However, your formula will not work as you try to take `sqrt` of a negative number.

Comment: What is this formula for? Can it go complex? You should put a `.` after your function name  `km` to broadcast over elements in the range. So write `km.(...)`. You can, instead, follow @BogumiłKamiński's suggestion for broadcasting. I must say I would go broadcasting with function call (`km.(...)`) as it is the more standard way of doing so with Julia, if your function needs to access only one element per result. Also do not use global variable within your function it prevents performance optimization, take them as parameters. You can use `deg2rad` function instead of `d` variable.

Comment: That said, your problem is not about plotting, but solely about computation.

Comment: Good point - it depends where you want to do the broadcasting but I agree that to define `km` in terms of scalars and only broadcast this function is more standard.

Comment: @BogumiłKamiński, thanks for the `@.`, I didn't know about this macro!

Comment: I withdrew my answer because broadcasting at the function level is fastest:     const x = rand(50000);
const y = rand(50000);

noinline function f1(a,b)
    sqrt.(a.*a + b.*b)
end;

noinline function f2(a,b)
    sqrt(a*a*2 + b*b)
end;


println("f1 x 3");
time f1(x,y);
time f1(x,y);
time f1(x,y);
println("f2 x 3");
time f2.(x,y);
time f2.(x,y);
time f2.(x,y);